# How can I use Node.js in html to use mysql data?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I think it's funny to say 'using Node.js in html'
but i want to know

First, I have less base of related knowledge of this
I want to make my website with mysql data (some data in it). and i wanna bring my data to use data when I program.

I made my html and some javascript codes in it.
As far as I know, Node.js is used to connect mysql to javascript.(This is not sure. I just learned myself)

So, how can I use mysql data when I code javascript in html by using node.js??
Are there some other solutions of this?

Sorry the questions aren't clear.

Comment: I suggest learning how to use [express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html) to create a basic website. Once you have the basics down (including pug templates), learn how to access a mySQL db with node, then combine everything to insert db data into your templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Node.js *in HTML*.

A `<script>` element in an HTML document can be used to run JS, embedded in a webpage, in the JS engine that is embedded in a browser.

Node.js is a way to run JS that is **not** embedded in a browser.

The traditional way to use Node.js in combination with a web page is to write an HTTP server in Node.js (typically using the Express.js module) and then communicate with it from JS in the page (usually with Ajax but sometimes with WebSockets or Socket.io).

You can also generate HTML documents directly from the Node.js HTTP server instead of using a web service.